# Nested eager loading dynamically created in a constrain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

songs table

```
  id  version  number
   1   AAA     1
   2   BBB     1
   3   CCC     1
   4   DDD     2
   5   EEE     3
   6   FFF     4
   7   GGG     4
```

The objective is to obtain, for example, all songs that have the same **number** as the song with id 1 (songs with ids 1, 2 e 3)

Song model

```
public function songs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Song::class, 'id_hierarchy');  
}
```

Query: it doesn't work it's just for demonstration (there is no **sameNumber** model)

```
public function readSongsVersions()
{
    $data = Hierarchy::query()
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with([
            'children.songs'
            'children.songs.sameNumber'
        ])
        ->get();
}
```

There is no sameNumber model.

Theoretically, a relationship would have to be created in the model song and it would be a relationship with the model song itself; Is such a solution possible?

The solution will eventually go through a constraint.

```
 $data = Hierarchy::query()
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with([
            'children.songs'
            'children.songs' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('number', '=', function($query) {
                        $query->select(DB::raw('i.number)'))
                            ->from('songs as i')
                            ->whereRaw('i.number = songs.number')
                        });
                },
        ])
        ->get();
}
```

How to nest in eager loading the result of the subquery ( 'children.songs' => function ($query) {...}) to get the sameNumber music collection for each song;

the equivalent of: 'children.songs.**sameNumber**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create relationships, that references itself. A where statement to ensure, not the same row is returned, since you are relying on the number column.

In `Song.php`

```
public function sameNumber()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Song::class, 'number', 'songs.number')
        ->whereColumn('version', '!=', 'songs.version');
}
```

There is one part you have to figure out, but when you run the code it should be fairly obvious, `'version'` and `'number'` columns are gonna be ambiguous and you have to check what naming `Laravel` uses, when dealing with tables named the same. Change the code like so `songs2.version`, dependent on the naming. You can also always call `->toSql()` on the relationships to see the SQL query.